# Possible GDI Leak when ReDrawing CButton's

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc, gdi

I have a problem when re-sizing a CControlBar that contains a few CButtons. After re-sizing for a while, the whole display breaks and stops painting correctly.
Based on what I can find about these kinds of issues, I am thinking that I am leaking GDI objects when the Button's are re-drawn.

Below is my DrawItem method. I keep finding different methods to use online but I still get the problem.

Please can someone help me pinpoint exactly what I need to change and how.

```
void CNJABarFolderButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)  {    

    UINT uState=DFCS_BUTTONPUSH;
    if( lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_SELECTED )
    {
        uState|=DFCS_PUSHED;
    }

    CDC dc;

    dc.Attach(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    dc.DrawFrameControl(&lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem,DFC_BUTTON,uState);
    if( !IsWindowEnabled() )
    {
        dc.SetTextColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_3DSHADOW));     
    }

    CString csText;
    GetWindowText(csText);

    if (m_iDisplayType != 2 || !m_hIcon)
    {
        CFont font;
        LOGFONT lf;
        memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT)); 
        lf.lfHeight = m_iFontSize;                      
        strcpy(lf.lfFaceName, "Tahoma Bold");       
        VERIFY(font.CreateFontIndirect(&lf));  

        CFont* def_font = dc.SelectObject(&font);

        RECT buttonRect = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;
        buttonRect.left += 10;
        buttonRect.right += 10;

        if (m_iDisplayType != 1 || !m_hIcon) //text & Icon
        {
            buttonRect.left += 30;
            buttonRect.right += 30;
        }   
        dc.DrawText(csText,&buttonRect,DT_LEFT|DT_SINGLELINE|DT_VCENTER);   

        dc.SelectObject(def_font);

        font.DeleteObject();
    }

    if (m_hIcon && m_iDisplayType != 1)
    {   
        CSize czText = dc.GetTextExtent(csText);
        dc.DrawIcon(0,0,m_hIcon);
    }
    dc.Detach();
}
```

Comment: If on Windows 7, did you use Task Manager to monitor the number of GDI objects of your process?